# Google Tag Manager :Auto Tracking Event Enquiry

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am new to Google Tag Manager and I have some clarification on incorporating to my website after researching on it.

-Does it means that I need to have some tag or trigger value like which button that my website has or what links that I need to track to put into the Google Tag Manager? Can GTM auto detect and display to me that what is the percentage the links in my website are accessed or which button is being clicked?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The GTM helps you, to configure your tracking. If you want to track a button or link click, you have to configure a Link Click or Click Trigger and fire a tag for that.

There is a good blog about the GTM: https://www.simoahava.com/

Comment: Alright. That means that I have manual configure the tracking to track the URL or button in my website? There is no feature in GTM that will auto track the forms, buttons or links without me specifying the "Submit"  button in the variable or event?

Comment: There are Triggers for
[**Form Submit**](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/)  and [**Button / Link Clicks**](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en#Click)

You have to activate and configurate them.